# PHP OOP Pagination

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pagination

I'm having an issue with pagination. I've debugged as mush as I can and it seems there is an issue with the SELECT query and execution. If I take out the pagination part the query executes and displays all entries in a long table. I tried executing an array, bindValue and bindParam but nothing works, can anyone see what I'm missing?

```
function showEmployees() {
  $count = $this->dbh->query("SELECT * FROM employee_info");
  $count->rowCount();
  $count = $count->rowCount();

  // if ($count > 0) {
  //    echo "The total amount of employees is " . $count;
  // } else {
  //    echo "There are no records in this table.";
  // }

  $page_rows = 10;
  $last_page = ceil($count / $page_rows);

  echo $last_page;

  if ($last_page < 1) {
    $last_page = 1;
  } 

  $page_num = 10;

  if (isset($_GET['pn'])) {
    $page_num = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['pn']);
  } 

  if ($page_num < 1) {  
    $page_num = 1;
  } elseif ($page_num > $last_page) {
    $page_num = $last_page;
  } 

  $limit = 'LIMIT ' .($page_num -1) * $page_rows .', '. $page_rows;     

  $query = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM employee_info ORDER BY employee_id DESC :page_limit");
  $query->bindParam(':page_limit', $limit );
  $query->execute();


  $t = "<table name='displayEmployees' border='1' >";
  $t .="<tr>";
  $t .= "<th>Employee ID</th>";
  $t .= "<th>First Name</th>";
  $t .= "<th>Last Name</th>";               
  $t .= "</tr>";

  while($u = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $t .="<tr>";
    $t .= "<td>{$u['employee_id']}</td>";
    $t .= "<td>{$u['first_name']}</td>";
    $t .= "<td>{$u['last_name']}</td>"; 
    $t .="</tr>";
  }

  $t .="</table>";

  return $t;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It think it's the way you handled the limit although that should have tripped an error.

Try:

```
$beginLimit = ($page_num-1)*$page_rows;
$endLimit = $page_rows;
$query = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM employee_info ORDER BY employee_id DESC LIMIT :begin,:end");
$query->bindValue(':begin',(int)$beginLimit,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindValue(':end',(int)$endLimit,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
```

Comment: Many thanks Casey, unfortunately I'm not permitted to vote up but this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't include keywords as parameters to your prepared statements. You'll need to do this:

```
 $limit = 'LIMIT ' .($page_num -1) * $page_rows .', '. $page_rows;       
 $query = "SELECT * FROM employee_info ORDER BY employee_id DESC ".$limit;
 $query->query($query);
```

Note: because the parameters are already sanitised by your script you *can* trust them, so the benefit of a prepared statement is largely lost in this case.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I understand what you said and appreciate it, due to paranoia of injection I got so much into the habit of preparing all statements I do it without thinking but you're correct, in cases such as this it is redundant, and sorry I am not yet permitted to vote.